# Getting latest modified date for a list of files from network

Tags: java, scala

I have a service which fetches a list of files from network, with each file inside a custom object.

What I want is find latest modified date among all of them, which I plan to do as:

```
val latestModifiedTime = fileService
    .fetchFiles(...)
    .map(_.file)
    .map(file => Files.getLastModifiedTime(file.toPath).toMillis)
    .sorted(Ordering.Long.reverse)
    .head
```

But I am not sure of this approach, due to toPath usage. Would it work with file fetched from network?

Secondly, if it works, then can it be mocked in unit test?

Comment: When you say read from network, do you mean network mounted filesystem (Windows or Linux) or a network access with some other app like FTP?

Answer (score 1):

If you are scanning network mounted filesystem you can use `Files.find` to scan file with attributes and filter the stream with a suitable comparator on the last modified time:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path dir = Path.of(args[0]);

    try(var files = find(dir, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (p,a) -> a.isRegularFile())) {

        var latest = files.max(Comparator.comparing(entry -> entry.getValue().lastModifiedTime()));
        if (latest.isPresent())
            System.out.println(latest.get().getKey() +" modified "+latest.get().getValue().lastModifiedTime());
    }
}
```

To make `find()` collect `Path` with `BasicFileAttributes` use this stream:

```
public static Stream<Map.Entry<Path, BasicFileAttributes>>
find(Path dir, int maxDepth, BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> matcher, FileVisitOption... options) throws IOException {

    // Using ConcurrentHashMap is safe to use with parallel()
    ConcurrentHashMap<Path,BasicFileAttributes> attrs = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> predicate = (p,a) -> (matcher == null || matcher.test(p, a)) && attrs.put(p, a) == null;
    return Files.find(dir, maxDepth, predicate, options).map(p -> Map.entry(p, attrs.remove(p)));
}
```